# How to output a list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, csv

I had some data in a `long` format and I needed to convert it into a `wide` format. I have just achieved this objective but now I am struggling with how to export that file as a CSV.

Upon checking it looks like my wide data is a data frame with lists in it. Partial data is copied below:

##### dput()

```
dput(my_list)

structure(list(
id = c(428593707L, 430722191L, 430848712L, 431317885L, 432493351L, 435125247L), 
`A1-ROL_SDRA_1_NA_score` = list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "2.1", NULL), 
`A1-RW_SDRA_1_NA_score` = list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "2.1", NULL), 
`A1-RW_SENS_1_NA_score` = list(NULL, NULL, "2.2", NULL, NULL, NULL), 
`A2-MW_SBIO_1_NA_score` = list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), 
`A2-MW_SWS_1_NA_score` = list(NULL, "1.2", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), 
`C1-AT_SADV_1_NA_score` = list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), 
`C1-AT_SBUS_2_NA_score` = list("3.1", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), 
`C1-AT_SENS_1_NA_score` = list(NULL, NULL, "2.1", NULL, NULL, NULL), 
`C1-AT_SENS_2_NA_score` = list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),  
row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

#### Existing answers

I have tried the following solutions:

###### Solution 1

```
t <- as.data.frame(my_list)
write.csv(t, "wide_data.csv", row.names = F)
```

I get the following error message `Error in utils::write.table(t, "wide_data.csv", row.names = F,  : unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'`

###### Solution 2

I have also tried saving it as a list, based on this link https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/erer/versions/3.0/topics/write.list

```
library('erer')
write.list(my_list, file = "wide_data.csv")
```

But I get this error `Error in write.list(my_list, file = "wide_data.csv") : Need an 'list' object.` And this is understandable as the my_list data is a dataframe of lists.

###### Solution 3

I tried the `tibble()` solution as well:

```
t <- my_list %>% as_tibble()
write.csv(t, "wide_data.csv", row.names = F)
```

Again, I get the error `Error in utils::write.table(t, "wide_data.csv", row.names = F,  : unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'`

###### Solution 4

I have tried column bind as well.

```
t = as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, my_list))
write.csv(t, "wide_data.csv", row.names = F)
```

Again, I get the error `Error in utils::write.table(t, "wide_data.csv", row.names = F,  : unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'`

###### Solution 5

I have tried row bind in the following way:

```
t = my_list %>% bind_rows()
write.csv(t, "wide_data.csv", row.names = F)
```

Again, I get the error `Error in utils::write.table(t, "wide_data.csv", row.names = F,  : unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'`

Can anyone advise how I can export this dataframe of lists as a CSV? I have been struggling for the past few days over this problem, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `do.call(rbind,my_list)` what you're looking for?

Comment: Someone smarter than me will likely provide you a solution, but it seems that a this may be better handled "upstream" (i.e., there may be a problem when pivoting from long to wide that you can address). Good luck!

Comment: You cannot export a list column to plain CSV. You need to either convert it to atomic types or export it to something like JSON.

Comment: @jpsmith
You may be right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution seems to have worked. Thanks, @Ian Campbell

```
# Row bind
df = do.call(rbind, my_list)

# Take transpose
df2 = t(df)

write.csv(df2, "test.csv", row.names = F)
```

Comment: One caveat: although you can export the list columns in this way, you won't be able to use `read.csv` to read your columns back into R as lists again.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ekoam, I just ran the ```read.csv``` and it is working fine :)

Comment: If you look into your data more carefully, the columns are not of type `list` anymore. They are now of type `character`. The key point is that you won't be able to get them back into R as **lists**. @Sandy

Comment: Yes, I agree. The list structure is no more. But I don't want the lists anymore, so at least for this data, I am good to go :)